# Unexpected limit result (was: How to fix the limit problem?)

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations, system-limitations

MATHEMATICA fails in proving that

```
Limit[
  Integrate[
   x^(x - 1)
   , {x, t, 2*t}
   ]
  , t -> 0
  , Direction -> "FromAbove"
  ] == Log[2]
```

**How to fix the problem?**

Comment: Maple gives `ln(2)` as the result of limit.

Comment: Ideally, `AsymptoticIntegrate[x^(x - 1), {x, t, 2 t}, {t, 0, 1}, Assumptions -> t > 0]` would calculate this result. It fails though, not sure why.

Comment: For the `Series[Integrate[x^(x - 1), {x, t, 2 t}], {t, 0, 1}] // Normal` Mathematica gives wrong answer: `t (-1+2 Log[2]+Log[t])`, this shoud be `Log[2] + t (2 Log[2]+Log[t]-1)`. Looks like a bug ...

Answer (score 4):

First do a series-expansion of the integrand around $x=0$:

```
Series[x^(x - 1), {x, 0, 1}]
(*    1/x + Log[x] + x*Log[x]^2/2 + O(x^3)    *)
```

then integrate:

```
Integrate[%, {x, t, 2 t}]
(*    Log[2] + t^2 (3/8 - Log[2] + Log[2]^2) + t (-1 + Log[4]) + 
      1/4 t (4 + t (-3 + Log[256])) Log[t] + 3/4 t^2 Log[t]^2       *)
```

then take the limit $t\to0^+$:

```
Limit[%, t -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]
(*    Log[2]    *)
```

Only the dominant $1/x$ term in the integrand matters in this limit.

Answer (score 2):

```
Series[Integrate[x^(x - a), {x, t, 2 t}], {t, 0, 1}] // Normal
```

gives

```
(2^-a (-2 + 2^a) t^(1 - a))/(-1 + a)
```

then taking `Limit`:

```
Limit[%,a->1]
```

gives `Log[2]`. Something similar is discussed in "Possible Issues" of `AsymptoticIntegrate`: result of the more general case differs from a simple one.